# Styling embedded Tumblr blog with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've successfully embedded my Tumblr Blog on my website using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://BLOGNAME.tumblr.com/js"></script>
```

I've also managed to style the body/content of the posts in CSS with

```
#tumblr_body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    color: #000000;
}
```

Now I want to change the style of each posts title to make these bold i.e. I tried to implement this with another `div` in the CSS file with `#tumblr_title` but this does no effect. Do you guys have any solutions to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Can you please provide the link or demo or live link so we can test it then we can give better solution.

Comment: You have to use the class selector `.` in the css and not the id selector `#`.  -> `.tumblr_title { font-weight: bold;}` .

Comment: that worked out, thanks! is there also a way to add dividers between the posts by using the `<hr>` tag f.e.?

Comment: You probably can't change the HTML, but you can try adding a `border-bottom` instead.

Comment: @colddev please provide the theme code, possibly in a jsfiddle, so we can test it.